# html edit code image

Tags: html, css

I Have following HTML code :

```
<img src="itw1.gif" height="10" width="40" /> 
<img src="itw2.gif" height="20" width="30" /> 
<img src="itw3.gif" height="30" width="20" /> 
<img src="itw4.gif" height="40" width="10" />
```

And i wanted to know how can i change the second image pass to have a green    border,the last two images start to have a blue border (both in one
CSS command) and all page images start to have half of his father's size
(in one CSS command)

I am having many difficulties to do so because in the first part I thought if Grub the "figure" but not, and the border do not know how to do it in a single application and do not understand how do the images have half of his father's size

Comment: <img src="itw1.gif" height="10" width="40" />
    <img src="itw2.gif" height="20" width="30" />
    <img src="itw3.gif" height="30" width="20" />
    <img src="itw4.gif" height="40" width="10" />

Comment: I think it's not possible in CSS for an image to have half of his father's size but you can do it in javascript.

Comment: `CSS Command`... `width: 50%;` or `.span{width: 50%; height: 10px;}`?
To add border, use `border: {width}px {style} {color}`. To make something half size of parent: `img { height: 50%; }`

Comment: @XavM What do you think `height: 50%` do?

Comment: @Justinas I thought the image should have half size of another image but after reading the problem a again, I'm wrong. height: 50% is right